# MSMQ on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2008, msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed MSMQ on Win 2008 Server R2 and it has no public queue node. Do you know how to fix this? Server runs in a domain. Domain controller is Win 2003.

Comment: mine has the node and I can create queues in it with right click and New command in the menu. Try to check Add new windows features... it could be a custom feature under MSMQ node to enable.

Comment: @Al Bundy - I'm assuming that you are trying to get a server up and running for easing your work at the shoe store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSMQ has an extra component for integration with AD.
Just installing on a domain member machine will not necessarily select this option.
Run setup again and ensure AD integration is selected. 
(I don't have a 2008 R2 machine handy to state exactly what the option is called).

If the option IS selected then check event logs for errors.
Usually a security issue creating the required AD objects.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: AD integration selected. I guess Domain Controller needs to be set up to support public queues. Anyway, we are using private queues now :)

Comment: Active Directory already has all the MSMQ schema information it needs to support public queues. AD Integration mainly just creates objects in AD for the member machine(s) that will be hosting or accessing public queues. Domain controllers don't need to run MSMQ.

Comment: The item you need to check/select is under Message Queueing -> Message Queueing Services -> Directory Service Integration